# Can I import .mov files with embedded closed captioning into Premiere Pro CS6?

Tags: premiere, cs6

I'm importing .mov files that have embedded closed captioning because I need to do some very minor edits. I know that I cannot export .mov files with embedded closed captioning, but can I also not get at that closed captioning data from anywhere within Premiere Pro CS6 after importing?

I need the files coming out the other end with closed captioning available, whether as a sidecar file or not, so I'm hoping there's some way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You might try [CCExtractor](http://ccextractor.sourceforge.net/about-ccextractor.html). I'm not sure if it supports text tracks in .MOV containers, but it's a good starting point. I can create .SRT files which are common companion files for captioning.

Comment: [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) can also extract subtitle streams from .mov files. something like `ffmpeg -i input.mov -map 0:s output.srt` should work, where input.mov is your movie file and output.srt is the name of the srt you want to create.